# How would you create a static version of the UIPopoverView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uipopovercontroller

I tried using a popover in my interface, but all the convenience features of the UIPopoverController made it impossible.

My goal is to use the popover's chrome, but none of the associated events or actions. I need it to stay displayed onscreen (no dismissal) and not be modal.

So now I'm considering building my own view using images. My question: is there a better way to accomplish this (a view with image borders)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay your UIPopover onscreen and allow the user to interact with other views onscreen while to popover is show, consider using the `passthroughViews` property on `UIPopoverController`

The [UIPopoverController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When a popover is active, interactions
>   with other views are normally disabled
>   until the popover is dismissed.
>   Assigning an array of views to this
>   property allows taps outside of the
>   popover to be handled by the
>   corresponding views.

You should be able to achieve the effect you want by just passing an array containing only the "background" viewcontroller's view.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that property. It almost solves my problem (interacting with my view works now) but a tap in my tabBar dismisses it (so you have to tap again to go to a different tab). How would I include the tab bar in the passthoughViews? I tried self.tabBarController.tabBar, no good.

Comment: Have you tried self.parentViewController.view or self.tabBarController.view?